# 2D game development with SDL2 + Lazarus + Pascal weird bug

Tags: windows, pascal, sdl-2, lazarus

I'm working on a *MOBA* game with space jets where 4 player teams compete each other.
I'm using latest realease of *Lazarus IDE* with *FPC 3.0* and *SDL2.0.5* and Windows 7.

**DESCRIPTION OF THE GAME:**
The player can fly his jet by pointing the destination with *mouse* and pressing *ENTER*. The jet moves in x/y axis in 4000*4000 area with output window 800*600. Look at the .gif below, it is taken from the upper most area of the level. Look how smooth and fluid is the movement of the jet.*(The actual game is even smoother but I didn't want to exceed stacks image size limits.)*

[image]

**DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM:** When one flies the jet to the BOTTOM or RIGHT side of the 4000*4000 area, it does not respond to the space input smoothly, although the Pascal console recognizes the input normally as with the other sides. It is as if it skips calculations. See the .gif below for the effect at the far bottom.

[image]

**WHAT IS NOT GOING WRONG:**

- It is NOT the OS. I tried it in WinXP and Linux both compiling and playing and the result is the same.
- It is NOT the PC. I tried it in several machines.
- It is NOT the *collision detection* code. I disabled it and it produces the same result.
- It is not the *camera* code. I disabled it and it produces the same result.
- It is not the press *ENTER* to give destination and *move* code. I checked line by line. I rewrote it. It is always the same.

**WHAT I THINK IS HAPPENING:** I think that the fact it happens only BOTTOM and RIGHT leads to the point that somehow it tries to stretch(?) the level texture... something like that. Any ideas?

Sorry for my bad English.

**EDIT:** Here is my CAMERA that follows my jet code.

```
   //UP                                                           //<--------clip blit  //
  if (shipy <= wheight/2)then                                                              //
   begin                                                          //
       cliprect^.x:= shipx-round(wwidth/2);                                                          //
       cliprect^.Y:=1;                                                                   //
   end;                                                                                  //
  //DOWN                                                                         //
  if ( shipy >= 4000-(wheight/2) ) then                                                         //
     begin                                                    //
         cliprect^.x:= shipx-round(wwidth/2);                                                        //
       cliprect^.Y:= 4000 - wheight-1;                                                               //
    end;                                                                                 //
  //LEFT                                                                       //
   if(shipx <=wwidth/2) then                                                              //
      begin                                                       //
        cliprect^.x:=1;                                                                  //
       cliprect^.Y:= shipy-round(wheight/2);                                                          //
        end;                                                                             //
   //RIGHT                                                                              //
   if (shipx >=(4000-(wwidth/2))) then                                                          //
    begin                                                         //
      cliprect^.x:=4000-wwidth-1;                                                                 //
      cliprect^.Y:= shipy-round(wheight/2);                                                           //
      end;                                                                               //
                                                                                         //
                                                                                         //
                                                                                         //
     //=========CORNERS=========//                                                        //
                                                                                         //
                                                                                         //
     //UP - LEFT                                                                   //
      if (shipy <= wheight/2) AND   (shipx <= wwidth/2) THEN                                 //
       BEGIN                                                                             //
                                                                 //
        cliprect^.x:=1;                                                                  //
        cliprect^.Y:=1;                                                                  //
       END;                                                                              //
                                                                                         //
      //UP - RIGHT                                                                    //
         if (shipy <= wheight/2) AND   (shipx >=4000-(wwidth/2)) THEN                           //
       BEGIN                                                                             //
                                                                  //
        cliprect^.x:=4000-wwidth-1;                                                               //
        cliprect^.Y:=5;                                                                  //
       END;                                                                              //
                                                                                         //
       //DOWN LEFT                                                                 //
         if (shipy >= 4000-(wheight/2)) AND   (shipx <=wwidth/2) THEN                           //
       BEGIN                                                                             //
                                                                  //
        cliprect^.x:=1;                                                                  //
        cliprect^.Y:=4000-wheight-1;                                                               //
       END;                                                                              //
                                                                                         //
                                                                                         //
       //DOWN- RIGHT                                                                    //
        if (shipy >= 4000-(wheight/2)) AND   (shipx >=4000-(wwidth/2)) THEN                         //
       BEGIN                                                                             //
                                                                  //
        cliprect^.x:=4000-wwidth-1;                                                               //
        cliprect^.Y:=4000-wheight-1;                                                               //
       END;                                                                              //
                                                                                         //
                                                                                         //
                                                                                         //
                                                                                         //
                                                                                        //
   if (shipy >wheight/2) AND ( shipy < 4000-(wheight/2)) AND  (shipx > wwidth/2) AND  (shipx < 4000-(wwidth/2)) then      //
    begin                                                                               //
   cliprect^.x:=shipx-round(wwidth/2);                                                             //
   cliprect^.Y:=shipy-round(wheight/2);                                                            //
                                                             //
      end;                                         //<--------------CAMERA----------//
```

Comment: Do some debugging. Trace log the relevant internal vars. Then it will become obvious what is happening. Really, debugging is the forgotten skill of programmers.

Comment: My guess from an initial glance is that the problem lies into that you change both coordinates while you are only sure that one exceeded its limits.

Comment: The jet travels the 4000*4000 area and the 800*600 pixel camera follows it till the edges. I changed the big area in diffferent sizes. The problem stays the same. I rewrote the code so that the camera is the one that travels with the jet stack at the middle, and at edges the jet travels the half area of the 800*600 pixel camera. Nope. The exact same problem is re-produced.